# Django reusable app for like functionality as in friendfeed

Tags: python, django

I am looking to implement "like" functionallity a bit similar as they do in [friendfeed](http://friendfeed.com). Is there a django reusable app that already does this?

Thanks!
Nick.

Comment: Go to http://www.djangoproject.com/community/ and ask this question.

Comment: Why the down-votes and sniping? It's not a particularly well-asked question but it's certainly valid and by definition programming related. (it's pretty hard to do anything with Django without programming as it's a web programming framework!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing you should just write yourself from scratch. A 'like' in its most basic form is going to be an object with relations to a user and some other object. Look at the [contenttypes framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) docs to see how to use generic foreign keys for this. The only other thing you need to worry about is to make the create view idempotent.

If you're new to django this is probably a fun little exercise to familiarise yourself with contenttypes. If you're not new, the whole app should take you less than an hour. I wouldn't go searching for a pluggable app either way.

Comment: I took your advice, and a bit of inspiration from the voting app as it is developed in pinax, and build my own thingy. As you said, the exercise was well worth it, I'm relatively new to django and pinax, and I learned something here.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your own together using parts of [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/).

There isn't one app that would do this for you as it's too specific and reusable Django apps are supposed to be very focussed.

Answer (score 0):

Search http://djangoplugables.com/